# How to record multitrack in Audacity?

Tags: usb, audio-recording, audacity

I have an Alesis 8 channel USB 2.0 Multimix. I can connect it to the computer through an USB port, obviously. How can I use Audacity to record multiple tracks from it, and have them separate inside Audacity? I can record all tracks together just fine; I want to know how to have them stored in separate tracks digitally. Currently they all go to the same one.

**EDIT:** Using Windows XP. To clarify, I'm recording multiple inputs on the mixer to a single track in Audacity. I'd like to have one track per input.

Comment: What OS?  To clarify, you're currently recording multiple inputs on the Alesis to a single track in Audacity, correct?  Or are you getting multiple tracks in Audacity, but only saving to one project file and need to be saving to one file per track?

Comment: Audacity forums: http://forum.audacityteam.org/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article, [Multichannel Recording](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Multichannel_Recording), should clarify the situation.

Audacity does provide multi-channel recording, but being able to use this
is very dependent upon the O/S and the sound card.

Comment: Is Multitracking, recording 2 tracks at once, for example, one from sound to headphones and the other to the computer's mic?